# How to Get and Post JSON with a connection between Swift and Rest API?

Tags: json, swift, rest

I am currently writing an Internal App for a company as a part of my education. So I haven't programmed in Swift before and the company has given me excess to an external REST server they have written, which provides GET,POST,PUT and DELETE and requires the servername, dbname, dbscheme and the table name. The REST server returns a JSON object.

I already searched for answers before but they are mostly for local Rest servers or the code is for older Swift versions. Please help me if you know how I could handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at this [Tutorial.](https://medium.com/@calvinw/using-urlsession-to-retrieve-json-in-swift-1-getting-started-d929f3a49c67)
It's very basic but you will learn how to use the [URLSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession) class.

I have written this very basic helper class for sending requests:

```
class WebRequest
{
    static func getAsync(_ urlString: String, callback: @escaping (Data?, Error?) -> Void)
    {
        let url = URL(string: urlString)

        let request = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:
        {
            data, response, error in

            callback(data, error)
        })

        task.resume()
    }

    static func postAsync(_ urlString: String, callback: @escaping (Data?, HTTPURLResponse?) -> Void)
    {
        let url = URL(string: urlString )
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler:
        {
            data, response, error in

            let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse
            callback(data, httpResponse)
        })

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
WebRequest.getAsync(url)
{
    data, error in

    if let error = error
    {
        // Error Handling
    }
    else if let data = data
    {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let myObject = try? decoder.decode(YourCodableDataModelClass.self, from: data)

        if let object = myObject
        {
            // Your JSON was parsed successfully.
        }
        else
        {
            // Object coould not be loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

In order for this to work, your class should implement the [Codable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) protocol.

Comment: Thank you for your help I will definitely have a look at the tutorial and your answer and will possibly give feedback, if it worked in the coming week